# How to scale Pixi.js Graphics consistently based on screen size

Tags: graphics, 2d, scaling, pixi.js

When drawing graphics with Pixi, they appear fine on mobile devices however on desktop the graphics appear very small as the renderer is a different size, currently set to the size of the window.

I realise I need to scale my graphics, however I am unsure what is the best way of achieving this consistently so that they look proportionate across all (or most) screen sizes, whether it be desktop or mobile.

```
document.body.appendChild(this.app.view);
this.app.renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
this.app.renderer.view.style.display = "block";
this.app.renderer.autoResize = true;
this.app.renderer.antialias = true;
this.app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xe6f9ff;
this.app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

I then draw a graphic...

```
this.playerSprite.beginFill(0xff6961);
this.playerSprite.drawRect(0, 0, 24, 24);
this.playerSprite.endFill();
this.app.stage.addChild(this.playerSprite);
```

I understand I can scale graphics using a scale factor of some kind...

```
this.playerSprite.scale.x = someScaleFactor;
this.playerSprite.scale.y = someScaleFactor;
```

However, what is the best scale factor in order to maintain the best proportions for my graphics while scaling them for different devices? Should I select a target size then scale up or down from there? Like so...

```
this.xScale = window.innerWidth / 411;
this.yScale = window.innerHeight / 731;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `resolution` property on your app to match `window.devicePixelRatio`

Also note that `PIXI.Text` has it's own `resolution` property that is independent of the `Application.resolution` property.